# Weak form of the Navier-Cauchy equation

Tags: finite-element, integration, variational-calculus

I am trying to obtain the weak form of the Navier-Cauchy equation, which is

$$- \rho \omega ^2 \textbf{U} - \mu \nabla ^2 \textbf{U} - (\mu + \lambda) \nabla (\nabla \cdot \textbf{U}) = \textbf{F}$$

and can be written in the component form

$$-(2 \mu +\lambda) \frac{\partial ^2 U_1}{\partial x_1 ^2} - \mu \frac{\partial ^2 U_1}{\partial x_2 ^2} - (\mu + \lambda) \frac{\partial ^2 U_2}{\partial x_1 \partial x_2} - \rho \omega ^2 U_1 = F_1$$

$$-(2 \mu +\lambda) \frac{\partial ^2 U_2}{\partial x_2 ^2} - \mu \frac{\partial ^2 U_2}{\partial x_1 ^2} - (\mu + \lambda) \frac{\partial ^2 U_1}{\partial x_1 \partial x_2} - \rho \omega ^2 U_2 = F_2$$

The general procedure is to multiply the PDE by a test function $\textbf{v}$ in the space $\textbf{V}$, or $v$ in the space $V$, and integrate it over the domain $\Omega$. I will proceed with the component form, for I believe it is easier for me to understand. Setting $\textbf{F} = 0$ and rearranging the terms

$$-(2 \mu +\lambda) \int_\Omega v \left[ \frac{\partial ^2 U_1}{\partial x_1 ^2} + \frac{\partial ^2 U_2}{\partial x_2 ^2} \right]dxdy - \mu \int_\Omega v \left[ \frac{\partial ^2 U_1}{\partial x_2 ^2} + \frac{\partial ^2 U_2}{\partial x_1 ^2} \right]dxdy -(\mu + \lambda)\int_\Omega v \left[  \frac{\partial ^2 U_2}{\partial x_1 \partial x_2} + \frac{\partial ^2 U_1}{\partial x_1 \partial x_2} \right]dxdy - \rho \omega ^2 \int_\Omega v \left[ U_1+U_2 \right]dxdy = 0$$

From Green's theorem I know that
$$ \int_{\Omega} \left(v \frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial x ^2} \right)dxdy = \int_\Gamma \left(v \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \hat{n}_x \right)ds - \int_{\Omega} \left( \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \right)dxdy$$

Which is sufficient to deal with the first and second integrals. However, I do not know how to proceed with the cross derivatives $\partial ^2 / \partial x_1 \partial x_2$ of the third integral. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: I have asked a similar question before, but I realized I have simplified the PDE too much and could not proceed with the given answers. Now I made a more detailed question in the hope this will clarify the problem.

Comment: There is another way of doing so: https://fenicsproject.discourse.group/t/weak-form-of-the-navier-cauchy-equation/3694/3?u=luc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The identity you're missing from Gauss' divergence theorem is:

$$
\int_\Omega \nabla \varphi \cdot\mathbf{v}
=
-\int_\Omega \varphi\nabla\cdot\mathbf{v}
+\int_{\partial\Omega}\varphi\mathbf{v\cdot n}
$$

where I've written $\varphi$ as an arbitrary scalar field.
So, using the divergence of $\mathbf{u}$ as the scalar field you'd get

$$
-\int_\Omega(\lambda+\mu) \nabla(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{u}) \cdot\mathbf{v}
=
\int_\Omega (\lambda+\mu)(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{u})\nabla\cdot\mathbf{v}
-\int_{\partial\Omega}(\lambda+\mu)(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{u})\mathbf{v\cdot n}
$$

and you can complete your weak formulation.

---

### Anyway, here's in a few more steps:

Note the divergence of the product (scalar*vector)
$$\nabla\cdot(\varphi\mathbf{v})=\nabla\varphi\cdot\mathbf{v}+\varphi\nabla\cdot\mathbf{v}$$
Rearrange to get
$$\nabla\varphi\cdot\mathbf{v}=\nabla\cdot(\varphi\mathbf{v})-\varphi\nabla\cdot\mathbf{v}$$
And plug it into that integral
$$\int_\Omega\nabla\varphi\cdot\mathbf{v}
=
\int_\Omega\nabla\cdot(\varphi\mathbf{v})-\int_\Omega\varphi\nabla\cdot\mathbf{v}$$
Apply Gauss' divergence theorem for vector fields in that second integral
$$\int_\Omega \nabla\cdot\mathbf{v}=\int_{\partial\Omega}\mathbf{v\cdot n}   \quad\Rightarrow\quad\int_\Omega \nabla\cdot\mathbf{\varphi v}=\int_{\partial\Omega}\varphi\mathbf{v\cdot n} \qquad\Rightarrow$$

$$\int_\Omega\nabla\varphi\cdot\mathbf{v}
=
\int_{\partial\Omega}\varphi\mathbf{v\cdot n}-\int_\Omega\varphi\nabla\cdot\mathbf{v}$$
Remember that $\varphi=\nabla\cdot\mathbf{u}$, enter Lamé's parameters, and voila:
$$(\lambda+\mu)\int_\Omega\nabla(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{u})\cdot\mathbf{v}
=(\lambda+\mu)\left(
\int_{\partial\Omega}(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{u})\mathbf{v\cdot n}-\int_\Omega(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{u})\nabla\cdot\mathbf{v}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Can I just ask if you have used only Gauss' divergence theorem or something in addition to it? I haven't found this identity the way you wrote it.

Comment: Oh... I guess I could've broken it down in a few more steps. I'm not sure if the correct term for it is this but, as I understand it, this is a flavor of the product rule for derivatives. One that stems from the divergence of a vector field multiplied by a scalar field:
$$\nabla\cdot(\varphi\mathbf{v}) = \varphi\nabla\cdot\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{v}\cdot\nabla\varphi$$

And here I've used it together with the formal presentation of Gauss' divergence theorem. Authors usually skip it, as I did, to save some time... but I agree that it isn't the best way to present it to those who are learning

Comment: You will find this and more in 

Gurtin (1981) page 30 equation 2;

Kind of old school, but a great book for continuum mechanics, nonetheless

Comment: Oh, sure, first year of Calculus... Once again, thank you. I appreciate the old books though!

Answer (score 3):

The general form of the equation is
$$
\frac{\partial \sigma_{ij}}{\partial x_j} + F_i = \rho \frac{\partial^2 U_i}{\partial t^2}
$$
where the stress is given by
$$
\sigma_{ij} = \sigma_{ij}(U) = 2 \mu \varepsilon_{ij} + \lambda \varepsilon_{kk} \delta_{ij}, \qquad \varepsilon_{ij} = \varepsilon_{ij}(U) = \frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{\partial U_i}{\partial x_j} + \frac{\partial U_j}{\partial x_i}\right)
$$
We are using the Einstein summation convention. It is better to derive the weak form here.

If $V_i$ is the test function
$$
\int_\Omega V_i \frac{\partial \sigma_{ij}(U)}{\partial x_j} dx = \int_{\partial\Omega} V_i \sigma_{ij}(U) n_i ds - \int_\Omega \sigma_{ij}(U) \frac{\partial V_i}{\partial x_j} dx
$$
In this equation, we have summation over both indices i and j. Since $\sigma$ is symmetric tensor, you can show that
$$
\sigma_{ij}(U) \frac{\partial V_i}{\partial x_j} = \sigma_{ij}(U) \varepsilon_{ij}(V)
$$
Hence you can use this form
$$
\int_\Omega V_i \frac{\partial \sigma_{ij}(U)}{\partial x_j} dx = \int_{\partial\Omega} V_i \sigma_{ij}(U) n_i ds - \int_\Omega \sigma_{ij}(U) \varepsilon_{ij}(V) dx
$$
The mathematical analysis of the weak formulation should be done in many books, e.g.,

S. Kesavan, Topics in Functional Analysis and Applications, Section 3.2.4

Comment: NSE is a parabolic system, so there is used only $\rho \frac {\partial U_i}{\partial t}$ and not second derivative.

Comment: @AlexTrounev, the question is about Navier-Cauchy (elasticity) and not about Navier-Stokes (Newtonian fluids) equations.

Comment: I was just about to say the same thing @nicoguaro. I understand the Navier-Cauchy equation is the time-harmonic form of the elastic wave equation.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't pay attention for the topic name.